# the meaning of 'distinction' here

Tags: word-meaning

The following is from The African Queen by C. S. Forester

> When she was only a girl he had attained the wonderful, almost mystic
>   **distinction** of the ministry, and was invested in her eyes with the superiority which that implied.

I looked up the dictionary and can't decide which one to be the meaning of 'distinction' here. Is it one of 'difference', 'eminence', and 'appearance'?

Comment: I would hazard that it is "eminence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that *he attained a unique quality that made him eminent*. I guess there isn't a single meaning here since the word **distinction** is quite broad, versatile, and flexible.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that it means *difference* (or *separation*). When Rose Sayer was a girl, her father being in the ministry (a preacher) separated him from other men (in her eyes), and made him different in an almost mystical way. I don't think that the Reverend Sayer was an *eminent* preacher in any way, although he was prepared to labour as a missionary in the heat of Africa.

> **distinction** noun (DIFFERENCE) [ C or U ]
>
> a difference between two similar things:
>
> - There's a clear distinction between the dialects spoken in the two regions.
> - This company makes no distinction between the sexes.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/distinction)